# JSTree adding nodes to child nodes

Tags: c#, jstree, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using JSTree with a MVC project and I am trying to add child nodes to the tree, however I am getting a null refference error Object reference not set to an instance of an object on the line `subGroupNode.children.Add(itemNode);` I guess this is because the `subGroupNode.Children` is empty. how can it be when the child is created in the previous foreach loop.

```
    public JsonResult GetJsTree3Data()
    {
        var marketGroups = new List<JsTree3Node>();

        // Create our root node and ensure it is opened
        var root = new JsTree3Node()
        {
            id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            text = "Market Items",
            state = new State(true, false, false)
        };

        foreach (var group in GenerateGroups(connString))
        {
            if (group.marketParentGroup == 0)
            {
                var node = JsTree3Node.NewNode(group.id_str);
                node.text = group.name;
                node.state = new State(false, false, false);
                marketGroups.Add(node);
            }
        }

         foreach (var marketGroup in marketGroups)
        {
            foreach (var subGroup in GenerateGroups(connString))
            {
                if (subGroup.marketParentGroup.ToString() == marketGroup.id)
                {
                    var childNodes = new List<JsTree3Node>();

                    var childNode = new JsTree3Node();
                    childNode.id = subGroup.id_str;
                    childNode.text = subGroup.name;
                    childNode.state = new State(false, false, false);

                    childNodes.Add(childNode);

                    var subGroupNode = new JsTree3Node();
                    subGroupNode.id = subGroup.id_str;
                    subGroupNode.text = subGroup.name;
                    subGroupNode.state = new State(false, false, false);
                    subGroupNode.children = childNodes;

                    marketGroup.children.Add(subGroupNode);
                }
            }
        }

        return Json(root, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see where you add `children` property to `subGroupNode` object

Comment: Thanks for replyng Nikolay, I thought I was adding the subChildNode in the line `subGroupNode.children.Add(itemNode);`

Comment: So isn't it that you should create that property and assign an empty array there first, before using the `Add` method (which I believe an array method) ? At least this is how it would work in javascript.

Comment: I have managed to remove the null reference by creating a new list and and trying to add child nodes to that list but this creates an infinte loop. I cant understand why its stuck in an infinate loop.

Comment: I added code to the second for each loop and I can now drill down into a second node, however when I click to expose the next node the node disapears I'm sure this is because I'm and setting the node and childs nodes to thte same Id. I'm not fluent in Linq but i think there may be a way to set the i'ds correctly using linq

Comment: Sorry, it were just my 2 cents there. I'm not familiar with those environments. You may want to open a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by creating a second list the same as the first and comparing those two lists.

```
 public JsonResult GetJsTree3Data()
    {
        var marketGroups = new List<JsTree3Node>();
        var marketSubGroups = new List<JsTree3Node>();

        foreach (var group in GenerateGroups(connString))
        {
            var node = JsTree3Node.NewNode(group.id_str);
            node.text = group.name;
            node.state = new State(false, false, false);
            node.parentId = group.marketParentGroup;
            marketSubGroups.Add(node);
        }

        // Create our root node and ensure it is opened
        var root = new JsTree3Node()
        {
            id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            text = "Market Items",
            state = new State(true, false, false)
        };

        foreach (var group in marketSubGroups)
        {
                var node = JsTree3Node.NewNode(group.id);
                node.text = group.text;
                node.state = new State(false, false, false);
                marketGroups.Add(node);
        }

        foreach (var marketGroup in marketGroups)
        {
            foreach (var subGroup in marketSubGroups)
            {
                if (subGroup.parentId.ToString() == marketGroup.id)
                {
                    var subGroupNode = new JsTree3Node();
                    subGroupNode.id = subGroup.id;
                    subGroupNode.text = subGroup.text;
                    subGroupNode.state = new State(false, false, false);
                    marketGroup.children.Add(subGroupNode);
                }
            }
        }

        root.children = marketGroups;

        return Json(root, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```